# How to check whether an EXTERNAL app has draw-over permissions in Android 7?

Tags: android, permissions, overlay, android-7.0-nougat

I am trying to check whether an external application (i.e. not the one I am writing, but another one running on the debug device) has draw-over permissions. However, regardless of the method I use, I always get *"false"* as answer, whence I know for certain that said application **can** draw over other apps. In fact, not only I explicitly gave it permissions through the Settings interface, but I actually witnessed it performing a view overlay.

This is the first method I used:

`pm.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, "target.package")`

This is the second method I used (packageInfo being the PackageInfo object associated with "target.package"):

```
boolean requestedPermissionGranted = false;

for (int i = 0; i < packageInfo.requestedPermissions.length; ++i) {
    if (packageInfo.requestedPermissions[i].equals(Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)) {
        requestedPermissionGranted =
            (packageInfo.requestedPermissionsFlags[i] & PackageInfo.REQUESTED_PERMISSION_GRANTED) != 0;
        break;
    }
}

hasPermission = requestedPermissionGranted;
```

Both expressions return false. By the way, I verified that `packageInfo.requestedPermissions` actually contains `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`.

I searched far and wide, but I could not find any topic that would answer my doubts. I only managed to find threads about how to check an app's **own** permissions, which I am **not** interested in.

P.S: I cannot use the shell through getRuntime().exec() and list active windows, as I get permission denied.

Comment: I don't know this for a fact, but it sounds like it's something that shouldn't be possible, with latest updates, Android took away your ability to know if a process is running, let alone its permissions, this is just a guess though.

Comment: This would be upsetting for my scenario. However, you can still know which processes are running in Android 7